# how to access local host in wamp when using proxy server

Tags: apache, proxy, localhost, wamp

I am using proxy server address proxy1.xxx.xxx.xx to connect the internet using port number 8888 and when i want to connect to my localhost project it bring error

```
The requested URL could not be retrieved
```

but if I did not use proxy server it work correctly

how can I configer to connect with proxy server on. I am working in wamp server 
here is my httpd.conf

```
ServerName localhost:81

HostnameLookups Off
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proxy can't see your local server because it only exists on your machine, and can't be accessed from the outside.

If you tell the proxy "connect to localhost", the proxy tries to connect to 127.0.0.1, which is its own machine, not yours.

If you want to do so, you must configure your webserver and router to accept remote connections on that port, and give the proxy your public IP address instead of localhost

Answer (score 0):

Try to allow the proxy to by-pass local addresses and add your localhost to the list of exceptions. To do  so using Chrome:

1. Go to Settings, Advanced Settings
2. Navigate to, Change proxy settings then LAN Settings
3. Click on the checkbox, Bypass proxy for local addresses as shown in the image below.

[Check: Bypass proxy for local addresses](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l2jev.png)

This should allow you to access your localhost from behind the proxy server.